# Open direct link not working

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush

The issue is that, when the user is logged in the mobile application and he receives a mobile push notification and clicks on it, then it takes to the specified URL mentioned in Open Direct of Mobile Push notification settings.

When the user is not logged in the mobile application and he receives a mobile push notification and clicks on it, it takes him to the login URL and upon giving credentials, it should redirect to the URL mentioned in Open Direct of Mobile Push notification. But it is not redirecting to that URL. What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 3):

The SDK is not responsible for handling the URLs within your application.  If there is a user flow then you should be looking internally to your implementation rather than the SDK.  (ref. https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/sdk-implementation/url-handling.html)